# how to remove git compare - + diff, the content is exact the same

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-diff, feature-branch

I have a feature branch and created a merge request, in the compare section, it shows me:

[image]
[image]

Pink is what dev branch looks like, green is my branch, the content on line 9 are exact the same, how can I modify my branch to make this diff disappear?

Comment: Are you sure the lines are exactly the same including whitespaces (space vs tabs) and end-of-lines (LF, CR, CR+LF)? Try `git diff --ignore-all-space`

Comment: I used notepad++, there are CR_LF on the left, that's the reason, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual diff is displayed as a comment :

```
\ No newline at end of file
```

Fix : add (and save) an empty line at the end of your file ...

---

Some text editors automatically remove the last line of a file on save if it is empty.

One way to revert the file to the version that was stored in git at version eacf32 is :

```
git checkout eacf32 -- file
```